# Display XML data in Razor View

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, view

I have XML Data in textbox and need display it after a link is clicked, in a new window.

```
<test>
  <to>Jack</to>
  <from>My</from>
  <heading>Test</heading>
  <body>This is body</body>
</test>
```

I don't need to display formatted XML, I need display just raw XML in browser as http://www.test.com/test.xml displayed.

Comment: ASP .NET MVC Razor View

Comment: can you tell me more about what kind of project you are working on. is it a Asp.net Api, Asp/.net MVC?

Comment: ASP .NET MVC and Razor

Comment: let me know if you have any issues with it!

Comment: I return model from controller that have a string contains XML data and save it to hidden textbox.

Comment: Do you want to show the XML content in Hidden text box in browser new tab or same tab ?

Comment: In a new browser tab

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as below.

```
return this.Content(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

or use a `<iframe>` tag as below

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("iframe1").style.display = "none";
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("iframe1").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
        <iframe src="Demo.XML" width="100%" id="iframe1" height="2000px" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" >           
         <xml>
           <id>1</id>
          </xml>
        </iframe>
    
    
    <button onclick="show();">show</button>
    <button onclick="hide();">hide</button>
```

Comment: Can not use this, because I return list and in the view I save xml string into a textbox. Really, I return model from controller that have a string contains XML data and save it to hidden textbox

Comment: if you want to save your xml to a textbox and you have a view for that, then why do you need to display a raw xml on browser. 

if you are doing it on test purpose then unhide the textbox.

Comment: I want when user click to button, display it in new window.

Comment: most you can do is use `iframe` as a canvas to display xml. refer my answer I have editted it.

Comment: Let me knoe if above answer suits your case?

Comment: No, I need to open in a new window